# How to return a variable in a function in kotlin

Tags: class, variables, kotlin, attributes

I created a function that recieves input and compare it to a list, when find a match it return the match, in this case this match is the attribute of a class that i created.

I understand that the problem is with the return statement, so in the beginning of the function I declare the return as "Any", further more than that I'm kinda lost.

The error is this: A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')

```
   class Class1(var self: String)       
   var test_class = Class1("")       

   fun giver(){       
       test_class.self = "Anything"       
   }

   class Funciones(){       
           fun match_finder(texto: String): Any{       
               var lista = listOf<String>(test_class.self)       
               var lista_de_listas = listOf<String>("test_class.self")       
               var count = -1       
               for (i in lista_de_listas){       
                   count = count + 1       
                   if (texto == i){       
                       lista_de_listas = lista       
                       var variable = lista_de_listas[count]       
                       return variable        

                   }       


               }       

           }       
       }           


   fun main(){       
       giver()       
       var x = "test_class.self"       
       var funcion = Funciones()       
       var y = funcion.match_finder(x)       
       println(y)       

   }
```

Comment: your `fun match_finder` must return a value. Currently it does not return anything when your text is not found.

Comment: How can I do that?, I mean in which closing bracket should I put it, and how sould I put it?, Im just learning sorry if its an obvious question

Answer (score 1):

To explain you what the problem is, let's consider the following code:

```
class MyClass {
    fun doSomething(): String {
        val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3)
        for (number in numbers) {
            if (number % 2 == 0) {
                return "There is at least one even number in the list"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you try compiling it you'll get the same error message as in your question: `A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')`. Why is that?

Well, we defined a function `doSomething` returning a String (it could be any other type) but we're returning a result only if the list of numbers contains at least one even number. What should it return if there's no even number? The compiler doesn't know that (how could it know?), so it prompts us that message. We can fix the code by returning a value or by throwing an exception:

```
class MyClass {
    fun doSomething(): String {
        val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3)
        for (number in numbers) {
            if (number % 2 == 0) {
                return "There is at least one even number in the list"
            }
        }

        // return something if the list doesn't contain any even number
        return "There is no even number in the list"
    }
}
```

The same logic applies to your original code: what should the function return if there is no `i` such that `texto == i`?

Please also note that the solution you proposed may be syntactically correct - meaning it compiles correctly - but will probably do something unexpected. The `for` loop is useless since the `if/else` statement will always cause the function to return during the first iteration, so the value `"There is no match"` could be returned even if a match actually exists later in the list.

Comment: in the second iteration why there is no a return? Why only happen in the first?, could you help me underdtand that?, this is a code I created in python, and as im learning kotling im adapting

Comment: @DiegoVenteSeminario in your solution, you have an `if/else` inside your loop: during the first iteration the value will either enter the `if` branch or the `else` branch.  Since both branches have a `return` the function will exit immediately and the loop will not continue to the 2nd iteration. Your original code would have worked in python because if you don't write any `return` the function will add a `return None` for you, while in Java/Kotlin you need to be explicit and if you forget the `return` the compiler will complain (for the reason I wrote in my answer)

Comment: So if I put a return statement for the match and a miss match, the loop will finish as it has acomplish its purpose, but without the return statement the code wont work, is there a way to fix this?  I understand that i cant take out the value that i produce in my loop as when that happen the loop stops, is that right?

Comment: yes, if the loop terminates it means you didn't have any match, hence you can put a `return "There is no match"` **after** the loop, just before the end of your method (see the last `return` in my example)

Comment: I did that in my other post from where you sent me here, byou said that the return "there is no match" can be returned even if there is a match is a way to solve this?, I have already put the return before the end of my method and the same happens , in your example you return a String, and I want to return a member or a value from my loop without it stoping it

Comment: in the other post you have 3 `return`s: 1 if there is a match, 2 in the `else`, 3 at the end. If I understood what you want, you need to delete the 2nd. Also, you need to change the 3rd to `return "Not a match"`.

Comment: I did it, and the same result is the same the other iterations doesnt happen

Comment: the code in your other question is returning "Not a match" because `lista` and `lista_de_listas` contain different values: `lista` contains "Anything", "Something" and "Nothing", while `lista_de_listas` contains "test_class.self", "test_class.tipo" and "test_class.element". The loop body is hence executed 3 times (you can verify this by checking the value of `count` after the loop, and you'll see it is 2), and at the end "Not a match" is returned as expected..

Answer (score 0):

I searched online, if someone has the same problem, the correct code is as follows:

```
   class Funciones(){       
       fun match_finder(texto: String): Any{       
           var lista = listOf<String>(test_class.self)       
           var lista_de_listas = listOf<String>("test_class.self")       
           var count = -1
           var variable = " "
           for (i in lista_de_listas){       
               count = count + 1       
               if (texto == i){       
                   lista_de_listas = lista       
                   var variable = lista_de_listas[count]       
                   return variable        

               } else {
                   return "There is no match"
                  }      


           }  
        return variable     
       }       
   }
```